# Recognition SDcard on Vagrant Environment

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant

Does anyone know how to recognize SD card on Linux in Vagarnt?

- Vagrant 1.7.2
- Host: Windows7 (and Cygwin)
- Guest: Ubuntu15.04

At first I built Ubuntu CUI using

```
vagrant init ubuntu-15.04
vagrant up
```

in Ubuntu env:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y ubuntu-desktop
```

and I modified Vagrantfile by adding:

```
vb.gui = true
```

and modified to recognize SD card as USB device:

```
vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--usb', 'on']
vb.customize ['usbfilter', 'add', '0',
              '--target', :id,
              '--name', 'Any mass storage',
              '--manufacturer', 'Generic',
              '--product', 'Mass Storage Device']
```

but I can't recognize SD-card and device such as /dev/sdb or /dev/sdc is not generated.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1307:0310 Transcend Information, Inc. SD/MicroSD CardReader [hama]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04e6:5115 SCM Microsystems, Inc. SCR335 SmartCard Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  40G  0 disk
└─sda1   8:1    0  40G  0 part /
```

sda1 is my HDD.

By default, installing Ubuntu15.04 from VirtualBox GUI, SD card can be detected by just inserting SD-card. So I can't understand the difference of

- Installing Ubuntu from Vagrant with CUI --> add GUI environment
- Installing Ubuntu from VirtualBox with GUI

How should I add modification to use SD card via installing from Vagrant CUI?